# Connecting to Accumulo from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, thrift, thrift-protocol, accumulo

I have been trying to connect to Accumulo from NodeJS through the Thrift proxy, but have been unsuccessful.

```
var thrift = require("thrift");
var AccumuloClient = require("./AccumuloProxy");

var transport = thrift.TFramedTransport;
var protocol = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;

var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 42424, {
    transport: transport,
    protocol: protocol
});

var client = thrift.createClient(AccumuloClient, connection);

client.login("root", {'password': "password"});
```

When I try to login I get

```
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Expected protocol id ffffff82 but got ffffff80
```

Is anyone able to help me out and give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

---

**UPDATE:**

I modified `protocolFactory` line in the proxy.properties file located in Accumulo and restarted the proxy.

```
protocolFactory=org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol$Factory
```

I performed the same steps as above, but added a callback to the `createClient` call.

```
var login;
var client = thrift.createClient(AccumuloClient, connection, 
    function(err, success) { login = success });
```

This populates the login variable.  I then try to use that login variable to execute other functions

```
client.listTables(login, function(a) { console.log(a) })
```

results in

```
{name: 'TApplicationException', 
 type: 6,
 message: 'Internal error processing listTables'}
```

Trying to create a table

```
client.createTable(login, "testTable", 1, "", function(a) { console.log(a)})
```

results in

```
{name: 'AccumuloSecurityException',
 msg: 'org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloSecurityException: Error SERIALIZATION_ERROR for user unknown - Unknown security exception'}
```

See answer below.

Comment: This is basically two questions, plus an answer, all rolled into one question. I'd recommend to clean it up. That way it is hardly helpful and not necessarily a good fit for the Q&A model at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem existed because of the handling of the response back from Accumulo.  In the AccumuloProxy.js file when the login result is received and read in `AccumuloProxy_login_result.prototype.read` it will set the success as `this.success = input.readString()`

The `readString()` function will take the `Buffer` and call `toString()` using the `utf8` encoding.  This was resulting in characters showing up incorrectly.

I modified the `AccumuloProxy_login_result.prototype.read` function to set success as `this.success = input.readBinary()` so that a `Buffer` is returned.  This `Buffer` can be passed in to the other function calls and will get a correct result back from Accumulo instead of an Exception.

This was put in as an issue with Thrift [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2363) and has apparently been fixed in the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Accumulo uses the `compact` protocol, not the `binary` protocol. It also seems, that there is currently no compact protocol support available for NodeJS.

Please have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253724/connecting-from-c-sharp-to-accumulo) as well. It deals with C#, but nevertheless it can be helpful. There are also some solutions out there utilizing RabbitMQ or other message brokers, [see here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/accumulo-user/201205.mbox/%3CCALs3O6gPUSo9dEOvk2wscKiTdfgq1thE-1Cjjw41eUoQQxD2HA@mail.gmail.com%3E).

Comment: Do you have a link to where it says that Accumulo only uses the `compact` protocol and can't use the `binary` protocol?  It seems like you should be able to change the protocolFactory in the proxy.properties to use the `TBinaryProtocol`

Comment: No, sorry. BTW, what is it that you don't like about my answer?

Comment: Accumulo doesn't require you to use the `compact` protocol.  You can switch to using the `TBinaryProtocol` by changing the proxy properties file so it isn't a problem that there is currently no `compact` protocol support available for NodeJS.

Comment: The error message from your first question clearly indicates compact is **used**. But I never said, that compact is **required**. If you implied that, that's not my fault.